# How to remove trailing whitespace from file extensions and folders snow?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, file-extension, automator, whitespace

How can I remove trailing whitespace from file extensions and folders in snow leopard ?

Ideally I would be able to run a single command within a directory that would search and remove for all files and folders with trailing whitespace and their subfolders.

I couldn't seem to do this with automator.

It's a delicate operation I don't want to make mistakes with.

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n'
find ~/Desktop -mindepth 1 -depth | while read f; do
    new="$(dirname "$f")/$(basename "$f" | sed 's/ *$//')"
    [[ "$f" != "$new" ]] && mv "$f" "$new"
done
```

- Without `IFS=$'\n'`, the `f` variables read by `| while read f` wouldn't have leading or trailing spaces
- Changing `sed 's/ *$//'` to `sed 's/^ *//;s/ *$//` would remove spaces from the start as well

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Now that you mention it I would certainly like to remove the leading whitespace too. I'm a bit confused how the script would look in that case. Do mean remove `$'\n'` and  `| while read` to achieve this ?

Comment: `'s/^ *//;s/ *$//'` would also remove spaces at the start. I meant that without `IFS=$'\n'` none of the f variables read by `while read f` would have trailing or leading spaces.

Comment: If I enter the original on one line in Terminal I get: syntax error near unexpected token `do' and if run in a script i get command not found.

Comment: @timoto Was the single line version missing a semicolon after the `IFS=$'\n'` or something? The command not found error could be caused by trying to run the script like `script.sh` instead of `./script.sh` if it wasn't in your path.

Comment: Yes I'm running the script as `sudo ./script.sh` I also tried this on the cl `IFS=$'\n'; for d in {1..9}; do find ~/test -name '* ' -depth $d | while read f; do mv "$f" "$(sed 's/ *$//' <<< "$f")" done done` there was no error, but it just hung and did not return to the prompt.

Comment: @timoto `chmod +x script.sh` and don't use sudo... You'd need semicolons before the `done` keywords as well.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to change the attribute. OK so now your initial example works removing the trailing whitespace. Now I'm trying to remove the leading whitespace replacing the line `mv "$f" "$(sed 's/ *$//' <<< "$f")"` with `mv "$f" "$(sed 's/^ *//;s/ *$//' <<< "$f")"` so perhaps I've misunderstood ?

Comment: now that you have edited the script, do you not need to specify the string to look for ? eg `'* '` or `' *'`

Comment: @timoto You don't, I removed it to make it easier to modify the script to strip spaces at the start as well.

Comment: sorry for late turnaround, i tried your new script but got this error, line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `done'

Comment: whoops turns out I had DOS line breaks in there, had to convert to UNIX. So this works very nicely. Thank you.

Comment: sorry I'm not sure how I missed this but each time I run this script it returns: `invalid argument` do you know why that could be ?

Comment: @timoto It was caused by trying to do something like `mv ~/Desktop/untitled\ folder ~/Desktop/untitled\ folder`, but I edited the script again.

Comment: No longer removes trailing whitespace in filenames in macOS 10.11.6 using `#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n'
find ~/Desktop -mindepth 1 -depth | while read f; do
    new="$(dirname "$f")/$(basename "$f" | sed 's/^ *//;s/ *$//')"
    [[ "$f" != "$new" ]] && mv "$f" "$new"
done`