# How to remove leading whitespace from file and folder names?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, filenames, whitespace

How to remove leading whitespace from file and folder names? (I'm running OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard.)

As provided below by @Lri I was able to remove trailing whitespace using this:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n'
for d in {1..9}; do
    find ~/Desktop -name '* ' -depth $d | while read f; do
        mv "$f" "$(sed 's/ *$//' <<< "$f")"
    done
done
```

Now I'm trying to remove leading whitespace with this:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n'
for d in {1..9}; do
    find ~/Desktop -name '* ' -depth $d | while read f; do
        mv "$f" "$(sed 's/^ *//;s/ *$//' <<< "$f")"
    done
done
```

but it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two problems: first, you need the `find` command to look for names with spaces at the beginning instead of the end (`-name ' *'` instead of `-name '* '`).  Second, f is going to be the full path to the file, not just its name; this means the spaces aren't at the beginning of the string, they're just after the last slash (e.g. "/Users/timoto/Desktop/ spacedfile").  This is a little more complicated to handle; the easiest way I thought of was to split the path using `dirname` and `basename`, and remove leading spaces from just the base part.

Also, there should be no need to run the command 9 times at different depths; just use the `-depth` option (without a number), and it'll return results in depth-first order (i.e. deepest files before their containing directories), which should prevent problems with directories getting renamed out from under processing the files in them.

```
IFS=$'\n'
find ~/Desktop -name ' *' -depth | while read f; do
    mv "$f" "$(dirname "$f")/$(basename "$f" | sed 's/^ *//;s/ *$//')"
done
```

EDIT: my basename/sed command was way more convoluted than it needs to be; simplified it...

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the `-depth` flag... I edited [my answer to the original question](http://superuser.com/questions/402647/how-to-remove-trailing-whitespace-from-file-extensions-and-folders-snow) as well.

Comment: This no longer seems to work as expected in macOS 10.11.6 Now removes leading and training space from folders, and leading space from filenames, but not trailing space from filenames.